# Split each string from a paragraph

Tags: java, regex, algorithm

I am trying to split each string from a paragraph, which has proper grammar based punctuation delimiters like ,.!? or more if any.

I am trying to achieve this using Java. Here is my code.

```
private void printWords(String inputString) {
        String[] x = inputString.split("[.!,\\s]");
        for(String temp: x){
            System.out.println(temp);
        }

    }
```

Sample input String:

He is srk. Oh! I am a very good friend of srk.

My output:

```
He
is
srk

Oh

I
am
a
very
good
friend
of
srk
```

There is a problem here, It is having spaces as shown in the output. What should be my regular expression to split strings in any given paragraph, without spaces in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
String[] x = inputString.split("\\W+");
```

Comment: `[^\\w]` can be written `\\W`

Comment: I knew I had forgotten something. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a `+` to make your expression match *one or more* characters:

```
String[] x = inputString.split("[.!,\\s]+");
```