# Split each string from any given paragraph in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a textArea. I am trying to split each string from a paragraph, which has proper grammar based punctuation delimiters like ,.!? or more if any.

I am trying to achieve this using Javascript. I am trying to get all such strings in that using the regular expression as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621369/split-each-string-from-a-paragraph/16621449?noredirect=1#16621449)

But here, in javascript for me it's not working. Here's my code snippet for more clarity

```
$('#split').click(function(){
    var textAreaContent = $('#textArea').val();
    //split the string i.e.., textArea content
    var splittedArray = textAreaContent.split("\\W+");
    alert("Splitted Array is "+splittedArray);
    var lengthOfsplittedArray = splittedArray.length;
    alert('lengthOfText '+lengthOfsplittedArray);
  });
```

Since its unable to split, its always showing length as 1. What could be the apt regular expression here.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression shouldn't differ between Java and JavaScript, but the `.split()` method in Java accepts a regular expression string. If you want to use a regular expression in JavaScript, you need to create one...like so:

```
.split(/\W+/)
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/s3B5J/

Notice the `/` and `/` to create a regular expression literal. The Java version needed two "\" because it was enclosed in a string.

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: it ignores all of special chars, for example if you write `[asd]` then its output `asd`

Comment: Works good. In your DEMO, I have given input as Hello, stackoverflow!
It showed length as 3. Shouldn't it be 2?

Comment: as i said, it ignores special chars that means count them too

Comment: @srk You asked how to get the regular expression to work in JavaScript - which is what I provided. If you need it to do something specific more, explain. So is your main point to get all **words** in the textarea? Without the sentence punctuation? I'm happy to try and help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
textAreaContent.split(/\W+/);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\W+ : Matches any character that is not a word character (alphanumeric & underscore).
```

so it counts except alphanumerics and underscore! if you dont need to split `" " (space)` then you can use;

```
var splittedArray = textAreaContent.split("/\n+/");
```